# Does Genesis 9:5 prohibit killing oneself?

Tags: genesis, noah, soul

In Genesis 9:5, God says (KJV, emphasis mine):

> **And surely your blood of your lives will I require;** at the hand of every beast will I require it, and at the hand of man; at the hand of every man’s brother will I require the life of man.

I've read that the Rabbis understood the first line of this verse (emphasized in bold above) as prohibiting suicide, I guess understanding it to say that taking one's own life will be "required," or taken into account/judgment, by God. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: The following verse is more pertinent to your header question, I would say. _Whoso sheddeth man's blood, by man shall his blood be shed: for in the image of God made he man._ Genesis 9:6. Murdering one's own humanity is . . . . .  murder of a humanity, which is made in the image of God.

Answer (score 3):

Given that life is a gift from God, and that blood represents God-given life, that is why the Bible says such a lot about respectful use of blood. Not even animal blood was to be consumed by humans once God gave Noah and his descendants permission to kill animals for food. Its blood had to be poured on the ground before it was eaten:

> "Every creeping thing that is alive, to you it is for food; as the
> green herb I have given to you the whole; only flesh in its life - its
> blood - ye do not eat" Genesis 9:3-4 *Young's Literal Translation* (See Leviticus 17:11 & Deuteronomy 12:23.)

Then follows the verse you quote, though YLT renders it as, "And only your blood for your lives do I require...". The point is clear, however, that blood represents life. That is why God told Cain that his brother's blood was crying out to him from the ground, after Cain had murdered Abel (Genesis 4:10). Cain had taken Abel's God-given life away from Abel.

The text you quote even has God saying he will require animals that kill humans to "account" for that act! Whatever that means, the text seems to be arguing from the lowest to the highest, animals killing humans to be the lowest, humans killing humans being the highest degree - of sin. A person who kills himself or herself has taken their own God-given life. The text infers that the matter is so serious that God will surely notice. After all, he notices when even animals take away life from humans. This should impact our thinking on the matter, surely?

I am inclined to think that the answer is, "Yes, Genesis 9:5 prohibits killing oneself."

Comment: +1. Good answer - why not also quote Gen 9:6 as NigelJ suggests?

Comment: @Dottard - I could, indeed, as well as a whole load more verses, some in the N.T., but I'm trying to discipline myself to have a laser-like focus on the main point of the Q (not an easy thing to do!)